# Going for Masters in Germany after being a Research Student in Japan

Tags: masters, germany, japan

I am enrolled as a Research Student in Japan. I am still in my home-country, planning to come to Japan at the end of May 2022. My Research Studentship will valid till August 2022.

On the other hand, I have got accepted to study Masters in Germany, which will start at October 2022. Now after the research studentship, I want to go to Germany. In that case, do I have to come back to my home country or can I process my documents at the German Embassy in Tokyo?

Comment: I am voting to close since this is not really a question about academia.

Comment: What is your home country? That will determine what you need and how to apply to be able to get to Germany, not where you are in the meantime.

Comment: My come country is Bangladesh.

Comment: One thought: If you do so at the embassy in Japan and they require you to present additional documents, those might be difficult to obtain while being abroad.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost surely process your documents at the local German embassy - that's what their purpose is! But to be sure, feel free to check [the website](https://japan.diplo.de/ja-ja/service/termin-bot/902224).

Comment: That's a good idea. Let me emailed them the issue.

Comment: It's not clear at all whether this is their purpose! Their primary purpose (beyond diplomatic relations) is to provide consular services to their own citizens and citizens or residents of their host country. Providing consular services for third-country citizens who are present in the country for a short time might or might not be possible, but by no means necessary.

Comment: @user151413 So as an international student, I am not allowed to face the embassy?

Comment: @opu웃 I don't know, you'll have to check with them. I just said I disagree with the answer that this would be almost surely possible because this were the embassy's purpose.